# Add startup programs to Guest user

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, guest-account

I recently built a new PC, and my sister needs to copy some files and stuff like that with it.

Since I care about security, I enabled the guest user (I don't want to create a new user account or give her login access of my administrator account).

I know also that the Guest user is a risk for security so I want to program a "supervisor" service that prevents the user from doing certain things.

But I don't know how to run it as administrator as soon as the Guest user logs in (since the user folder resets at logoff).

So is there a way to start a program (or a service) as administrator as soon as Guest logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better accomplish what you wish (and because of the way Guest works), make your sister a Standard User. You are the Administrator.

So now she has the limits of a standard user and you can add whatever software you wish.

This will work better over the longer term.

Comment: The thing is that i don't wanna allow the local user to save data in the local drive, and disk quotes set to 0 are really buggy and don't work well (they are designed to be greater than 0)

Comment: Your restrictions are fairly onerous. You cannot set programs to run in Guest like you wish, but you can in Standard User. But then the standard user can save data in their own home folder..  Ask them not to.   You may wish to experiment with KIOSK mode in Windows 10.